# Why I am getting double jquery?

Tags: jquery

I was doing page analysis from of a [sample page](http://www.gtricks.com/chrome/extensions-to-block-sites-in-chrome/) on Pingdom and  GTmetrix, and I notices that I am getting jquery versions 1.7.2 and 1.8.3 in the page.

I have deregister jquery from functions.php and manually included(v. 1.8.3) in HTML code, which is also been shown at source code.

I can't understand from where v1.7.2 it is coming?

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins do not use the recommended method of `wp_enqueue_script()`, and instead bundle jQuery with the plugin (or use an external version) and load it through dropping a `<script>` tag into the page head.

Really, the only way to fix this is to  manually edit the plugin files and remove the duplicate call to jQuery. However, looking at your linked page, you only are loading jQuery 1.8.2?

Answer (score 0):

It may be comming from a plugin. You should deregister jquery and than register another jQuery (now your prefered version). Than all plugins will load only new version.